# how to get public events in graph facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please can someone tell me how to get facebook public events ?
I want to do something like this 
http://elmcity.info/fb_events?location=New%20York

Answer (score 2):

Use the /search endpoint `search?q=New York&type=event`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Comment: this only give events which has newyork in thier name

Comment: any other solution?